# How to resolve java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list error

Tags: scala

When both list1 and list 2 are empty, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWYar.png) error message.

```scala
def append(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if list1.isEmpty && list2.isEmpty then
    0
  if list1.nonEmpty && list2.isEmpty then
    list1
  else if list1.isEmpty && list2.nonEmpty then
    list2
  else if list1.tail.isEmpty && list2.nonEmpty then
    list1.head::list2
  else
    val x = append(list1.tail, list2)
    list1.head::x
}

test("append", append, "list1", "list2")
```

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question

Comment: This is missing `else` on the second `if`

Comment: Also, if you intend to return `0` in the first case, that won’t work when the method has a `List[Int]` return type. I would expect it to return an empty list in that case.

Comment: Please never ever link error as an image

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem is the missing `else`, but this is much cleaner if you use a `match`:

```
def append(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  (list1, list2) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) =>
      Nil
    case (a, Nil) =>
      x
    case (Nil, x) =>
      x
    case (a::Nil, b) =>
      a +: b
    case (a::tail, b) =>
      a +: append(tail, b)
  }
```

or just

```
def append(list1: List[Int], list2: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list1 match {
    case Nil =>
      list2
    case a :: tail =>
      a +: append(tail, list2)
  }
```

But neither of these are tail recursive so will have performance and memory issues for very large lists.